# Programming in VS Code with external Docker

Tags: visual-studio, docker

I'm working with VS Code installed at Windows 10. On this machine im running a Unix VM with Docker installed. How can I configure VS Code to connect to a remote docker instead of a local docker? HyperV and VMWare doesn't work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Install [docker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterJausovec.vscode-docker) for vscode. By default it connects to local docker daemon.You can set DOCKER_HOST to valid host to set it to any other host instead of local host